# How to write to an Excel spreadsheet using Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I need to write some data from my program to an Excel spreadsheet. I've searched online and there seem to be many packages available (xlwt, XlsXcessive, openpyxl). Others suggest writing to a .csv file (never used CSV and don't really understand what it is).

The program is very simple. I have two lists (float) and three variables (strings). I don't know the lengths of the two lists and they probably won't be the same length.

I want the layout to be as in the picture below:

[image: Layout sample]

The pink column will have the values of the first list and the green column will have the values of the second list.

So what's the best way to do this?

I am running Windows 7 but I won't necessarily have Office installed on the computers running this program.

```py
import xlwt

x=1
y=2
z=3

list1=[2.34,4.346,4.234]

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

sheet1.write(0, 0, "Display")
sheet1.write(1, 0, "Dominance")
sheet1.write(2, 0, "Test")

sheet1.write(0, 1, x)
sheet1.write(1, 1, y)
sheet1.write(2, 1, z)

sheet1.write(4, 0, "Stimulus Time")
sheet1.write(4, 1, "Reaction Time")

i=4

for n in list1:
    i = i+1
    sheet1.write(i, 0, n)

book.save("trial.xls")
```

I wrote this using all your suggestions. It gets the job done but it can be slightly improved.

How do I format the cells created in the for loop (`list1` values) as scientific or number?

I do not want to truncate the values. The actual values used in the program would have around 10 digits after the decimal.

Comment: You'll understand what a tsv file is if you open it in a text editor like notepad/wordpad. The key advantage to using tsv is that you can be confident that basically any version of any spreadsheet program can open it, and not only office 2010's excel

Comment: Use string format in python to control the display of the numerical data.

Comment: check [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to work with .xlsx files

Answer (score 108, accepted):

```
import xlwt

def output(filename, sheet, list1, list2, x, y, z):
    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sh = book.add_sheet(sheet)

    variables = [x, y, z]
    x_desc = 'Display'
    y_desc = 'Dominance'
    z_desc = 'Test'
    desc = [x_desc, y_desc, z_desc]

    col1_name = 'Stimulus Time'
    col2_name = 'Reaction Time'

    #You may need to group the variables together
    #for n, (v_desc, v) in enumerate(zip(desc, variables)):
    for n, v_desc, v in enumerate(zip(desc, variables)):
        sh.write(n, 0, v_desc)
        sh.write(n, 1, v)

    n+=1

    sh.write(n, 0, col1_name)
    sh.write(n, 1, col2_name)

    for m, e1 in enumerate(list1, n+1):
        sh.write(m, 0, e1)

    for m, e2 in enumerate(list2, n+1):
        sh.write(m, 1, e2)

    book.save(filename)
```

for more explanation:
    https://github.com/python-excel

Comment: You might want to mention that if you are running Python on Windows and have Excel installed on the same machine, you can use the Python COM interface to directly control Excel.

Comment: Just note that with this code maximum row limit is 65536 rows, as .xls files support only that many rows

Comment: To be clear, `xlwt` is only for writing the old `.xls` files for Excel 2003 or earlier.  This may be outdated (depending on your needs).

Comment: You can check [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to work with .xlsx files

Answer (score 174):

Use [DataFrame.to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) from [pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas). Pandas allows you to represent your data in functionally rich datastructures and will let you [read in](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files) excel files as well.

You will first have to convert your data into a DataFrame and then save it into an excel file like so:

```
In [1]: from pandas import DataFrame
In [2]: l1 = [1,2,3,4]
In [3]: l2 = [1,2,3,4]
In [3]: df = DataFrame({'Stimulus Time': l1, 'Reaction Time': l2})
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   Reaction Time  Stimulus Time
0              1              1
1              2              2
2              3              3
3              4              4

In [5]: df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

and the excel file that comes out looks like this:

[image]

Note that both lists need to be of equal length else pandas will complain. To solve this, replace all missing values with `None`.

Comment: Pretty sure pandas uses the xlrd/xlwt libraries for its excel capabilities http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files

Comment: I was assuming it used `xlwt` too, but getting an `openpyxl` error. For anyone else who gets confused by this - it's all in the filetype you want. The pandas (0.12) docs say "Files with a `.xls` extension will be written using xlwt and those with a `.xlsx` extension will be written using openpyxl".

Comment: Not sure why folks are saying it's overkill. For my purposes it was just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 41):

- **xlrd/xlwt** (standard): Python does not have this functionality in it's standard library, but I think of [xlrd/xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) as the "standard" way to read and write excel files. It is fairly easy to make a workbook, add sheets, write data/formulas, and format cells. If you need all of these things, you may have the most success with this library. I think you could choose openpyxl instead and it would be quite similar, but I have not used it.

  To format cells with xlwt, define a `XFStyle` and include the style when you write to a sheet. [Here is an example with many number formats](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/examples/num_formats.py). See example code below.
- **Tablib** (powerful, intuitive): [Tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a more powerful yet intuitive library for working with tabular data. It can write excel workbooks with multiple sheets as well as other formats, such as csv, json, and yaml. If you don't need formatted cells (like background color), you will do yourself a favor to use this library, which will get you farther in the long run.
- **csv** (easy): Files on your computer are either *text* or *binary*. Text files are just characters, including special ones like newlines and tabs, and can be easily opened anywhere (e.g. notepad, your web browser, or Office products). A csv file is a text file that is formatted in a certain way: each line is a list of values, separated by commas. Python programs can easily read and write text, so a csv file is the easiest and fastest way to export data from your python program into excel (or another python program).

  Excel files are binary and require special libraries that know the file format, which is why you need an additional library for python, or a special program like Microsoft Excel, Gnumeric, or LibreOffice, to read/write them.

---

```
import xlwt

style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.num_format_str = '0.00E+00'

...

for i,n in enumerate(list1):
    sheet1.write(i, 0, n, fmt)
```

Comment: You probably want to use the the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) included in the standard library if you're going to write a CSV file.

Comment: Not that it particularly matters, but Tablib, like so many other higher-level packages, uses xlwt to output Excel files.

Answer (score 16):

```
import xlsxwriter


# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20)

# Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

# Write some simple text.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')

# Text with formatting.
worksheet.write('A2', 'World', bold)

# Write some numbers, with row/column notation.
worksheet.write(2, 0, 123)
worksheet.write(3, 0, 123.456)

# Insert an image.
worksheet.insert_image('B5', 'logo.png')

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Adding missing link to the mentioned library: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 15):

I surveyed a few Excel modules for Python, and found [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to be the best.

The free book Automate the Boring Stuff with Python [has a chapter on openpyxl](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) with more details or you can check the [Read the Docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) site. You won't need Office or Excel installed in order to use openpyxl.

Your program would look something like this:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

stimulusTimes = [1, 2, 3]
reactionTimes = [2.3, 5.1, 7.0]

for i in range(len(stimulusTimes)):
    sheet['A' + str(i + 6)].value = stimulusTimes[i]
    sheet['B' + str(i + 6)].value = reactionTimes[i]

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

Comment: I get an error saying: cannot convert int64 to excel

Comment: I am definitely finding openpyxl to be a superior package.

Comment: `sheet['A' + str(i + 6)].value = stimulusTimes[i]` looks a lot harder than `dataframe( [1,2,3])` (panda example below)

Answer (score 12):

CSV stands for comma separated values. CSV is like a text file and can be created simply by adding the [.CSV extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

for example write this code:

```
f = open('example.csv','w')
f.write("display,variable x")
f.close()
```

you can open this file with excel.

Comment: You cannot format the column backgrounds using CSV. It is only a data format for import and export.

Comment: You probably want to use the the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) included in the standard library if you're going to do this. It handles quoting better, for example.

Comment: @Flimm how do i simply write to different cells?

Comment: if you are using Python 3 and the file contains non-ASCII characters, like `é` or `中`, you better do an `f.write('\xEF\xBB\xBF')` right after the `open()`. That is the BOM ([byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), q.v.), needed by Microsoft software to recognize the UTF-8 encoding

Answer (score 9):

The `xlsxwriter` library is great for creating `.xlsx` files. The following snippet generates an `.xlsx` file from a list of dicts while stating the **order** and the **displayed names**:

```
from xlsxwriter import Workbook


def create_xlsx_file(file_path: str, headers: dict, items: list):
    with Workbook(file_path) as workbook:
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        worksheet.write_row(row=0, col=0, data=headers.values())
        header_keys = list(headers.keys())
        for index, item in enumerate(items):
            row = map(lambda field_id: item.get(field_id, ''), header_keys)
            worksheet.write_row(row=index + 1, col=0, data=row)


headers = {
    'id': 'User Id',
    'name': 'Full Name',
    'rating': 'Rating',
}

items = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': "Ilir Meta", 'rating': 0.06},
    {'id': 2, 'name': "Abdelmadjid Tebboune", 'rating': 4.0},
    {'id': 3, 'name': "Alexander Lukashenko", 'rating': 3.1},
    {'id': 4, 'name': "Miguel Díaz-Canel", 'rating': 0.32}
]

create_xlsx_file("my-xlsx-file.xlsx", headers, items)
```

[image]

---

> Note 1 - I'm purposely not answering to the exact case the OP presented. Instead, I'm presenting a more generic solution IMHO most visitors seek. This question's title is well-indexed in search engines and tracks lots of traffic
>
> [image]
>
> Note 2 - If you're **not** using Python3.6 or newer, consider using `OrderedDict` in `headers`. Before Python3.6 the order in `dict` was not preserved.

---

Comment: I just came back to this post to thank you for this beautiful function _/\\_

Answer (score 7):

Try taking a look at the following libraries too:

[xlwings](http://xlwings.org) - for getting data into and out of a spreadsheet from Python, as well as manipulating workbooks and charts

[ExcelPython](https://github.com/ericremoreynolds/excelpython) - an Excel add-in for writing user-defined functions (UDFs) and macros in Python instead of VBA

Answer (score 3):

[OpenPyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable) is quite a nice library, built to read/write Excel `xlsx/xlsm` files.

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979532/5448626), referring to it is using the depreciated function `get_sheet_by_name()`. This is how to go without it:

```py
import openpyxl

# The 'New_file.xlsx' should be created before running the code.
# There must be a worksheet with the name "Sheet1" in it.

wbk_name = 'New_file.xlsx'        
wbk = openpyxl.load_workbook(wbk_name)
wks = wbk['Sheet1']
some_value = 1337
wks.cell(row=10, column=1).value = some_value
wbk.save(wbk_name)
wbk.close()
```

The `some_value` variable is written in the Excel file:
[image]

Comment: Above code produces error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'New.xlsx'`

Comment: @Atinesh - Thank you for the feedback - `openpyxl.load_workbook` loads a workbook, which is already present. Create a file `New.xlsx` to avoid this error.

Comment: OK Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Note that openpyxl does not support older 'xls' format.

Comment: @William Brochensque junior - I love to see my answers edited & improved, but take a look at the way the python variables are expected to be named - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308972/python-file-naming-convention

Comment: @Vityata no problem. Just thought it was hard to understand it at first! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @WilliamBrochensquejunior- no problem, I have updated it as well, hopefully now it is better :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to import the exact numbers is to add a decimal after the numbers in your `l1` and `l2`. Python interprets this decimal point as instructions from you to include the exact number. If you need to restrict it to some decimal place, you should be able to create a print command that limits the output, something simple like:

```
print variable_example[:13]
```

Would restrict it to the tenth decimal place, assuming your data has two integers left of the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [hfexcel](https://github.com/ebsaral/hfexcel) Human Friendly object-oriented python library based on [XlsxWriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter):

```
from hfexcel import HFExcel

hf_workbook = HFExcel.hf_workbook('example.xlsx', set_default_styles=False)

hf_workbook.add_style(
    "headline", 
    {
       "bold": 1,
        "font_size": 14,
        "font": "Arial",
        "align": "center"
    }
)

sheet1 = hf_workbook.add_sheet("sheet1", name="Example Sheet 1")

column1, _ = sheet1.add_column('headline', name='Column 1', width=2)
column1.add_row(data='Column 1 Row 1')
column1.add_row(data='Column 1 Row 2')

column2, _ = sheet1.add_column(name='Column 2')
column2.add_row(data='Column 2 Row 1')
column2.add_row(data='Column 2 Row 2')


column3, _ = sheet1.add_column(name='Column 3')
column3.add_row(data='Column 3 Row 1')
column3.add_row(data='Column 3 Row 2')

# In order to get a row with coordinates:
# sheet[column_index][row_index] => row
print(sheet1[1][1].data)
assert(sheet1[1][1].data == 'Column 2 Row 2')

hf_workbook.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your need is to modify an existing workbook, the safest way would be to use [pyoo](https://pypi.org/project/pyoo/). You need to have some libraries installed and it takes a few hoops to jump through but once its set up, this would be bulletproof as you are leveraging the wide and solid API's of LibreOffice / OpenOffice.

Please see my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JavaScriptDude/d5c9736a3ae41637c5622bdfecc8da22) on how to set up a linux system and do some basic coding using pyoo.

Here is an example of the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import pyoo
# Connect to LibreOffice using a named pipe 
# (named in the soffice process startup)
desktop = pyoo.Desktop(pipe='oo_pyuno')
wkbk = desktop.open_spreadsheet("<xls_file_name>")
sheet = wkbk.sheets['Sheet1']
# Write value 'foo' to cell E5 on Sheet1
sheet[4,4].value='foo'
wkbk.save()
wkbk.close()
```