# How to convert JSON to XLS in Python

Tags: python, json, xls

**Does anyone know how can I convert JSON to XLS in Python?**

I know that it is possible to create `xls` files using the package `xlwt` in Python.

What if I want to convert a `JSON` data file to `XLS` file directly?

Is there a way to archive this?

Comment: You need a programming language to map your hierarchical json structure to flat spreadsheet structure. You may want to convert it to csv instead of xls directly as there is plenty examples of that on the web (all spreadsheet editors read csv).

Comment: Another answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56315305/1437254 `pip install hfexcel`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I usually use tablib for this use. Its pretty simple to use:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tablib/

Comment: please note that this link is to a very old version of tablib (probably newest at the time) and it causes problems with newest versions of python, instead install tablib 3.0.0 version

Answer (score 32):

Using pandas (0.15.1) and openpyxl (1.8.6):

```
import pandas
pandas.read_json("input.json").to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: this command puts all the key:value pairs of a particulat {set} in the same row.

Answer (score 6):

If your json file is stored in some directory then,

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json("/path/to/json/file").to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

If you have your json within the code then, you can simply use DataFrame

```
json_file = {'name':["aparna", "pankaj", "sudhir", "Geeku"],'degree': ["MBA", "BCA", "M.Tech", "MBA"],'score':[90, 40, 80, 98]}
df = pd.DataFrame(json_file).to_excel("excel.xlsx")
```

Comment: I am getting this error ' If using all scalar values, you must pass an index'

Answer (score 2):

In case someone wants to do output to Excel as a stream using Flask-REST

Pandas versions:

```
json_payload = request.get_json()

with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.xlsx') as tmp:

    pandas.DataFrame(json_payload).to_excel(tmp.name)

    buf = BytesIO(tmp.read())

    response = app.make_response(buf.getvalue())
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'

    return response
```

and OpenPyXL version:

```
keys = []
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

json_data = request.get_json()

with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:

    for i in range(len(json_data)):
        sub_obj = json_data[i]
        if i == 0:
            keys = list(sub_obj.keys())
            for k in range(len(keys)):
                ws.cell(row=(i + 1), column=(k + 1), value=keys[k]);
        for j in range(len(keys)):
            ws.cell(row=(i + 2), column=(j + 1), value=sub_obj[keys[j]]);
    wb.save(tmp.name)

    buf = BytesIO(tmp.read())

    response = app.make_response(buf.getvalue())
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream'

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert any JSON (.json) file into Microsoft Excel you can try the below code snippet. And you are getting
`Value error: trailing data`

Example: your file name is `input.json`.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json(“input.json”, lines = True).to_excel(“output.xlsx”)
```

`output.xlsx` will be your required file