# Write dictionary of nodes with PageRank as value to Excel Python

Tags: python, excel, pagerank

I have an output text file as a post-calculated PageRank json dictionary.

Here's the sample result in text file:

```
{
  "exDict": {
    "chr10:100085400-100085600": 0.14285714285714285,
    "ENSG00000138131.3$LOXL4$chr10$100028007$-": 0.14285714285714285,
    "chr10:1001000-1002200": 0.33976972605163247,
    "ENSG00000107929.10$LARP4B$chr10$977564$-": 0.10506345360625002,
    "ENSG00000107937.14$GTPBP4$chr10$1034338$+": 0.10637024864027625,
    "ENSG00000148377.5$IDI2$chr10$1071799$-": 0.06847319265351563,
    "ENSG00000205740.1$AL359878.1$chr10$1034281$-": 0.09460909333404022
  }
}
```

Note:

"exDict" is the name of this dictionary.

"chr10:100085400-100085600" and "ENSG00000138131.3$LOXL4$chr10$100028007$-" are names of certain nodes.

"0.14285714285714285" is the PageRank value of that node.

I want to output it into csv/xls file into rows and columns. Is it possible to output this so that it has the following format?

[image]

Comment: Yes, of course. Some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15379178

Comment: Thanks a lot!This is what I looking for!@Rup