# How should I export results to excel from python when I don't konw the type

Tags: python

[how can i export the results to excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFCJr.png)

I tried to export the options' volumes from this website. But I find i can't export the results to excel bc I don't know the type of 'response'. How should I do?

Comment: please post code as code. also post copy-pasteable data

Comment: It's always better to add the code who have tried so far. For better and clear understanding. And provide more detail along with your code.

Comment: At first glance the output appears to be a JSON string. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379178/how-to-convert-json-to-xls-in-python) answer out.

Answer (score 1):

You cand try  openpyxl is a Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm/xltx/xltm files.

Library documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/