# Python Error: row index not an int in range(65536)

Tags: python, int

I am getting this message when writing to an excel file using xlwt:

> row index (u'RN') not an int in range(65536)

The line throwing the error come from here:

```
sheet.write(x,fieldKey, row.OBJECTID)
```

Where `x` is a counter I set to set the row value and `fieldKey` is another counter to set the column value.

I don't know why I am getting this message because the value (u'RN') is a string value, but it's telling me that it is not an int in range(65536). I believe the range(65536) is the limit of the excel table. Again, I was only writing 18 records, so I don't see why this error came up. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: As you say the value is a *string* `rn` which is **not an int** - nevermind the range part...

Comment: Why are you passing `u'RN'` as a column index/coordinate? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: Ahhhh...I've been working on this for hours. I just found that I set x as a variable buried deep in my script in another instance. I actually tried looking for that earlier, but it just hit me now. Jon, your post made me look again. thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you can not write to excel for more than 65536 lines. (You can now in the xlsx format). I had the same issue, try .to_csv()

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet) the args to sheet.write should be ycoord,xcoord,value

so it should be something like sheet.write(0,0,answer1)

edited based on responses.

Comment: It's easier to remember if you call them row and col instead of y and x. Then the order seems natural, instead of backward.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because `x` (the row index) isn't a number, but a string. Check the values you are passing to the `sheet.write` method; the first two must be numbers (try printing them before making the call).

Comment: Well, maybe not _clearly_, but it seems likely that if you have a counter named `x` and a key named `fieldKey`, it's the latter that would hold a string `u'RN'`. But you're right, I'm making an assumption that could be wrong.

Comment: Indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624942/python-error-row-index-not-an-int-in-range65536/17625067#comment25659474_17624942

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had through I was passing x as a number until it was overwritten with another x variable I had set. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can change in row.py inside the def **init**(self, rowx, parent_sheet) the limit, let's make it x2 for example:

```
if not (isinstance(rowx, int) and 0 <= rowx <= 131071):
```

changed from

```
if not (isinstance(rowx, int) and 0 <= rowx <= 65536):
```