# "TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'list'> in write()"

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I wish to print 'out.csv' data in excel file when the condition is not uppercase. But the data in out.csv is list of data instead of string. How do I write the list to excel file without converting it to string? (As I have other file which may need to use list instead of string)

Python version #3.5.1

```
import xlsxwriter
import csv
import xlwt

f1= open('out.csv')
data=csv.reader(f1)

# Create a new workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('1.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write some test data.

for module in data:
    str1 = ''.join(module)
    if str1.isupper():
      pass
    else:
      worksheet.write('A', module)


workbook.close()
```

Comment: Do you just want `worksheet.write('A', str1)`? I don't know anything about `xlsxwriter`, so I don't know if you can write out more than one item at a time.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305109/most-pythonic-way-to-write-list-to-xls-file
Also, why can't you have a string and a list version of what you want to write and use whichever is necessary?

Comment: my output in shell are [AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE],[FFF_GGG_HHH_III_JJJ] etc, which are a list in array form. But I wish to print those output in Excel file in column A1, A2, etc with a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I write the list to excel file without converting it to string

You could either loop over the list and `write()` out each element or you could use the XlsxWriter [`write_row()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-row) method to write the list in one go.

Something like this:

```
row = 0
col = 0
for module in data:
    str1 = ''.join(module)
    if str1.isupper():
        pass
    else:
        worksheet.write_row(row, col, module)
        row += 1
```