# Unable to write data into Excel file (multiple tabs) using Python

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, xlsxwriter

I am not much familiar with data writing in Excel format using Python, need some help to write my data output into single .xlsx (Excel) file with multiple tabs.

My code is given here:

```
import time
import requests
import random
from lxml import html 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter

def write_to_file(file, mode, data, newline=None, with_tab=None):  
    with open(file, mode, encoding='utf-8') as l:
        if with_tab == True:
            data = '\t'.join(data)
        if newline == True:
            data = data+'\n'
        l.write(data)

link = ["http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber="+str(var)+"&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods=" for var in range(17500)] # This will read the URL's line by line as per specific value of var.
start = 1 
end = 20 

for pagenum, links in enumerate(link[start:end]):
    print(links)
    r = requests.get(links)
    time.sleep(random.randint(2,5))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

# Table 2
    for items in soup.find(id="tblAccountContactInfo").find_all("tr")[:]:
        dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")[:]]
        print(dataset)

        write_to_file('Table3.tsv', 'a', dataset, with_tab=True, newline=True)
        write_to_file('Table3.tsv', 'a', links)

# Table 3
    for items in soup.find(id="tblChildDetails").find("table").find_all("tr"):

        dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")[:]]
        print(dataset)

        write_to_file('Table3.tsv', 'a', dataset, with_tab=True, newline=True)
        write_to_file('Table3.tsv', 'a', links)

        #workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Table3.xlsx')
        #worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 3")
        #worksheet.write(dataset)
        #workbook.close()
```

I need the output in .xlsx Excel sheet in multiple tabs like Table 1 tab and Table 2 tab, currently I am fetching data in .tsv format. I have tried the xlsxwriter but unable to get results so commented those line. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["TypeError: Unsupported type <class 'list'> in write()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050951/typeerror-unsupported-type-class-list-in-write)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first create two worksheets, and keep track of the current row to be used for each worksheet. An `append_row()` function can then add one row of data to the required sheet.

```
import time
import requests
import random
from lxml import html 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter


def append_row(ws, row):
    for col, value in enumerate(row):
        ws.write_string(ws.cur_row, col, value)

    ws.cur_row += 1


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
ws_2 = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 2")
ws_3 = workbook.add_worksheet("Table 3")

# Keep a track of the row to use in each worksheet
ws_2.cur_row = 0    
ws_3.cur_row = 0        

start = 1 
end = 3
link = "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber={}&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods="

for page_number in range(start, end):
    print("Page {}".format(page_number))
    url = link.format(page_number)
    r = requests.get(url)

    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    # Table 2
    for items in soup.find(id="tblAccountContactInfo").find_all("tr")[:]:
        dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")[:]]
        append_row(ws_2, [url] + dataset])

    # Table 3
    for items in soup.find(id="tblChildDetails").find("table").find_all("tr"):
        dataset = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")[:]]
        append_row(ws_3, [url] + dataset])

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin Evans for suggesting