# Python, appending printed output to excel file

Tags: python, csv, xlwt

I was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction, or give an example on how I can put the following script output into an Excel spreadsheet using xlwt.  My script prints out the following text on screen as required, however I was hoping to put this output into an Excel into two columns of time and value.  Here's the printed output..

```
07:16:33.354    1

07:16:33.359    1

07:16:33.364    1

07:16:33.368    1
```

My script so far is below.

```
import re

f = open("C:\Results\16.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
searchstrings = ['Indicator']
timestampline = None
timestamp = None
f.close()
a = 0
tot = 0

while a<len(searchstrings):
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        for word in searchstrings:
            if word in line:
                timestampline = searchlines[i-33]
                for l in searchlines[i:i+1]: #print timestampline,l,
                #print
                    for i in line:
                        str = timestampline
                        match = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}', str)
                        if match:
                            value = line.split()
                            print '\t',match.group(),'\t',value[5],
                            print
                            print
                            tot = tot+1
                            break

    print 'total count for', '"',searchstrings[a],'"', 'is', tot
    tot = 0
    a = a+1
```

I have had a few goes using xlwt or CSV writer, but each time i hit a wall and revert bact to my above script and try again.  I am hoping to print match.group() and value[5] into two different columns on an Excel worksheet.

Thanks for your time...

MikG

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Write to Excel Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of problems do you have with xlwt? Personally, I find it very easy to use, remembering basic workflow:

1. `import xlwt`
2. create your spreadsheet using eg.

   `my_xls=xlwt.Workbook(encoding=your_char_encoding)`,

   which returns you spreadsheet handle to use for adding sheets and saving whole file
3. add a sheet to created spreadsheet with eg.

   `my_sheet=my_xls.add_sheet("sheet name")`
4. now, having sheet object, you can write on it's cells using sheet_name.write(row,column, value):

   `my_sheet.write(0,0,"First column title")
   my sheet.write(0,1,"Second column title")`
5. Save whole thing using spreadsheet.save('file_name.xls')

   `my_xls.save("results.txt")`

It's a simplest of working examples; your code should of course use sheet.write(row,column,value) within loop printing data, let it be eg.:

```
import re
import xlwt

f = open("C:\Results\VAMOS_RxQual_Build_Update_Fri_04-11.08-16.txt", "r")    
searchlines = f.readlines()
searchstrings = ['TSC Set 2 Indicator']
timestampline = None
timestamp = None
f.close()
a = 0
tot = 0

my_xls=xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8") # begin your whole mighty xls thing
my_sheet=my_xls.add_sheet("Results")   # add a sheet to it

row_num=0 # let it be current row number
my_sheet.write(row_num,0,"match.group()") # here go column headers, 
my_sheet.write(row_num,1,"value[5]")      # change it to your needs
row_num+=1 # let's change to next row

while a<len(searchstrings):
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        for word in searchstrings:
            if word in line:
                timestampline = searchlines[i-33]
                for l in searchlines[i:i+1]: #print timestampline,l,
                #print
                    for i in line:
                        str = timestampline
                        match = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}', str)
                        if match:
                            value = line.split()
                            print '\t',match.group(),'\t',value[5],
                            # here goes cell writing:
                            my_sheet.write(row_num,0,match.group()) 
                            my_sheet.write(row_num,1,value[5])
                            row_num+=1
                            # and that's it...
                            print
                            print
                            tot = tot+1
                            break

    print 'total count for', '"',searchstrings[a],'"', 'is', tot
    tot = 0
    a = a+1
    # don't forget to save your file!
    my_xls.save("results.xls")
```

A catch:

- native date/time data writing to xls was a nightmare to me, as excel
  internally doesn't  store date/time data (nor I couldn't figure it
  out),
- be careful about data types you're writing into cells. For simple reporting at the begining it's enough to pass everything as a string,
  later you should find xlwt documentation quite useful.

Happy XLWTing!

Comment: Thanks GM Gray, your solution is exactly what I was looking for, I am hugely grateful, you have saved a lot of head scratching, and frustration! I normally code in Perl, so I have been a bit slow in switching languages.