# Download data using selenium

Tags: python, html, excel, selenium

I am a research analyst trying to collate data and perform analysis.I need data from this [page](http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/netprofit/bse/index.html) . I need data of Abrasives to vanspati Oils (you'll find it on left side). I always encounter problems like this, I figured out that selenium will be able to handle such stuff. But I am stuck on how to download this data into Excel. I need one excel sheet for each category.
My exact technical question is how do I address the problem of downloading the table data.I did a little bit of background research and understood that the data can be extracted if the table has class_name.[from here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html). I see that the table has `class="tbldata14 bdrtpg"` So I used it in my code.
I got this error

> InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector tbldata14 bdrtpg
>   is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

How can I download this table data? Point me to any references that I can read and solve this problem.
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/netprofit/bse/index.html")
elem=driver.find_element_by_class_name("tbldata14 bdrtpg")
```

Thanks in advance.Also please suggest if there is another simple way [I tried copy paste it is too tedious!]

Comment: Can't you find the same kind of data at yahoo/google/bloomberg which have direct downloads to excel?

Comment: I would like to have same business classification as that in moneycontrol. So it would be easy  to directly download this data from moneycontrol page.

Comment: You should refer to the Terms of Use for the moneycontrol web site to determine if this is even allowed by them.

Comment: Error is because you are selecting an entire table. I suggest using BeatuifulSoup instead of selenium: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/. Although it's possible to adjust xpath to select elements (something like `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='tbldata14 bdrtpg']//a/b")` - if I didn't mess it up, it should give you list of companies)

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the data you're interesting in can be achieved as following,

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/netprofit/bse/index.html"

# Get table-cells where the cell contains an anchor or text   
xpath = "//table[@class='tbldata14 bdrtpg']//tr//td[child::a|text()]"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
driver.get(url)
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)

# Group the output where each row contains 5 elements
rows=[data[x:x+5] for x in xrange(0, len(data), 5)]
for r in rows:
    print "Company {}, Last Price {}, Change {}, % Change {}, Net Profit {}" \
        .format(r[0].text, r[1].text, r[2].text, r[3].text, r[4].text)
```

Writing the data to an excel file is explained here,

- [Python - Write to Excel Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet)
- [Python, appending printed output to excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522282/python-appending-printed-output-to-excel-file?lq=1)