# Raw data to excel

Tags: python, excel, shell, csv

i have a file bundle.crd. The itens are like this

```
col1 val1 val2 val3 val4 
col2 val1 val2 val3 val4 
col4 val1 val2 val3 val4 
col5 val1 val2 val3 val4 
col6 val1 val2 val3 val4 
col7 val1 val2 val3 val4
```

I need this to be imported to an excel file in the following format.

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6 col7
-------------------------------------------
val1  val1  val1  val1  val1  val1  val1 
val2  val2  val2  val2  val2  val2  val2 
val3  val3  val3  val3  val3  val3  val3
val4  val4  val4  val4  val4  val4  val4
```

I tried this code but its not working

```
    lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
        grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 3)
        with open('extracted.csv', 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            #writer = csv.writer(out_file, dialect=csv.excel)
            writer.writerow(('title', 'intro', 'tagline'))
            writer.writerows(grouped)
```

Please Help

Comment: Can you be more clear about what is not working - are you getting an error? is it not giving the right output? something else?

Comment: It is storing it into the same format.ie; col1val1val2val3val4 into a single cell

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet?rq=1) might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Again how will I create the list if I dont know the number of elemets

Answer (score 0):

Did you split the lines into cells?

Here is an example, how to transpose a list of lists:

```
>>> values
[['col1', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], ['col2', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], ['col4', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], ['col5', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], ['col6', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], ['col7', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']]
>>> zip(*values)
[('col1', 'col2', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7'), ('val1', 'val1', 'val1', 'val1', 'val1', 'val1'), ('val2', 'val2', 'val2', 'val2', 'val2', 'val2'), ('val3', 'val3', 'val3', 'val3', 'val3', 'val3'), ('val4', 'val4', 'val4', 'val4', 'val4', 'val4')]
```