# How to copy CSV data to an existing xlsx file using Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, export

I am using Python 3.4 and I am writing a short script. I have an executable that take the output of a software and outputs a bunch of csv files with the requested data. I have created an Excel (xlsx) file as a template. It has a chart  tailored to specific requirements.

I want to take a certain range of that data in each of those csv files and then input them into the existing excel template I have already created and save it with a unique file name. Essentially iterate this process.

Each csv file will have a unique name. My goal is to help automate creating graphs. Sometimes this can end up being 100s of graphs. I have searched a lot on how to do this with little help.

Again I would initiate the script and it would run through each csv file (whether there is 5 or 500) and then copy the data (a certain range which is always in the same cells) then paste it into the template xlsx file I have created and save it with a similar name to the csv except it will have .xlsx as the extension.

I do not know if this is the best approach or if I should create a csv template instead that it will copy to.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are you planning to use to read/write the xlsx?

Comment: I have used the module [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) in the past.

Comment: I tried those but not so helpful. I was planning to use those excel module xlsxwrt, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

## 1st approach

If your end goal is to generate graphs from data available in csv then you can use csvReader to read data and matplotlib to plot graphs.

Simple example:

```
Sample csv file:
1,10,45
2,20,30
3,30,90
4,40,80

import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

keys = ['Col1','Col2','Col3']
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
fd = open('sample.csv','r')
reader = csv.DictReader(fd,fieldnames=keys)
for row in reader:
    col1.append(int(row['Col1']))
    col2.append(int(row['Col2']))
    col3.append(int(row['Col3']))

pp = PdfPages("Sample.pdf")

plt.title("Col1 Vs Col2")
plt.xlabel("X-Values")
plt.ylabel("Y-Values")
plt.plot(col1,col2,label="Label 1",marker = "*")
legend = plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=True, fontsize=6)
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('#00FFCC')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig(pp,format='pdf')
plt.clf()

plt.title("Col1 Vs Col3")
plt.xlabel("X-Values")
plt.ylabel("Y-Values")
plt.plot(col1,col3,label="Lable 2",marker = "*")
legend = plt.legend(loc='best', shadow=True, fontsize=6)
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('#00FFCC')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig(pp,format='pdf')
plt.clf()
pp.close()
```

References:

- http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

## 2nd approach

You can use xlrd,xlwt and xlutils to perform operation on excel files

Read data using csvReader, copy your existing template using xlutils, edit that and again save back

Reference:

- http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: This is great but the thing is I need to paste a certain data range of the CSV file (just numbers) into the existing Excel file that has plots created. I think it would be easier to just extract the range of CSV data and paste them into my Excel template. Is that possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get all files by using the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module:

```
   import glob
   csv_file_list = glob.glob('*.csv')
   for fyle in csv_file_list:
       data = read_csv(fyle)
       write_to_excel(data)
```

Your read_csv() function should accept a CSV file and create an array of arrays (matrix) with the data. It's common to use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module (which in Python 3 doesn't require the unicodecsv 'add-on').

If the data is just numbers and you don't have to worry about quoted fields, then it's much faster to just read the rows. So your read_csv() function would look like this:

```
with open(fyle,'rb') as input:
    data = input.readlines().split(delim)
return data
```

Then your `write_to_excel()` function would accept 'data' and write to your template.

Comment: This looks great but I want to paste the data I read from the CSV back into a certain range in my existing Excel template. Also The first 5 rows are quoted fields but I do not need them. The first 5 rows are text that are always created but not needed to transfer to my template. How do I make sure I get the 6th row and on (which are all numbers) from the CSV to get pasted into a certain part of my existing Excel template? Hope that made sense. thank you.

Comment: philshem how would the write_to_excel() function look like? I want to make sure I know how to write to the existing excel template I created.

Comment: @duranil There are many options, but probably something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437772/2327328) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437855/2327328) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13438050/2327328)