# Python scikit learn how to export classification report and confusion matrix result in excel?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

How to export result in excel file? I tried below script but its not giving meproper output. In the case where there is no dependent label present in **predicted** column and the class which is present in **test data** set it is not showing it in the output.

Is there any other way to achieve this. I want to present model result in the excel format.

```
import pandas as pd
expected = y_test
y_actu = pd.Series(expected, name='Actual')
y_pred = pd.Series(predicted, name='Predicted')
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred,y_test.unique())

df_confusion


df_confusion.to_csv('SVM_Confusion_Matrix.csv')

from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = ExcelWriter('SVM_Confusion_Matrix.xlsx')
df_confusion.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: This is a very detailed post with some great answers on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use following codes for classification report:

1. `classification_report = classification_report(y_actu, y_pred, output_dict=True)`
2. `df = pandas.DataFrame(classification_report ).transpose()`
3. `df.to_excel('classification_report.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

The function will create a data frame of confusion matrix with embedded Recall and precision scores. The data frame can then be easily exported to excel. Works with any number of categories

```
def confusion_max_df(actual, prediction, labels):
    """
    Input: A list of actual values, prediction values and labels
    returns: A data frame of confusion matrix embedded with precision and recall
    """
    
    # confusion matrix from sklearn.metrix library
    cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(actual, prediction,labels=labels)
    
    # calculatimg recall and precision at category label
    tp_and_fn = cnf_matrix.sum(1)
    tp_and_fp = cnf_matrix.sum(0)
    tp = cnf_matrix.diagonal()
    precision = [str(round(num, 2)*100) +'%' for num in list(tp / tp_and_fp)]
    recall = [str(round(num, 2)*100)+'%' for num in list(tp / tp_and_fn)]
    
    # creating dataframe for exporting to excel
    cnf_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(cnf_matrix, columns=labels)
    cnf_matrix_df = cnf_matrix_df.add_prefix('Predicted - ')
    actual_list = ['Actual - ' + str(x)  for x in labels]
    cnf_matrix_df['Confusion matrix'] = actual_list
    cnf_matrix_df = cnf_matrix_df.set_index('Confusion matrix')
    cnf_matrix_df['Recall'] = recall
    
    # adding a row in the dataframe for precision scores
    precision_row = ['Precision']
    precision_row.extend(precision)
    precision_row.append('')
    
    cnf_matrix_df.loc['Precision'] = precision_row[1:]
    
    return cnf_matrix_df

confusion_max_df(['Cat A','Cat A','Cat B','Cat B','Cat A','Cat B'],['Cat A','Cat A','Cat B','Cat B','Cat A','Cat A'],['Cat A','Cat B'])
```