# Use Python To Show All Combinations

Tags: python, combinations, xlwings

I am attempting to get all possible combinations of any number of series. How would I write a loop to get all the combinations and print them into an excel file?

Input

Series 1 A,B,C
Series 2 1,2,3
Series 3 X,Y,Z

Output

Combo 1 A,1,x

Combo 2 A,2,X

Combo 3 A,3,X

ect....

Comment: What series? Be specific and provide some examples.

Comment: This is the closest I got - however it is an excel formula. https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3097-excel-list-all-possible-combinations.html I am trying to recreate this in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: I added an answer below, but generally: please do some online research first before posting a new question. The way you ask sounds like "please solve my problem". If you provide *some* python code, e.g. just the three series as python lists, your question sounds more credible and you will get fewer downvotes

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product` to find all possible combinations:

```
s1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
s2 = [1,2,3]
s3 = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
from itertools import combinations
combos = itertools.product(s1,s2,s3)
```

As for writing into an excel file, please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet).

Comment: The other answer isn't wrong, but this answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Run three for loops, one inside the other:

```
for a in s1:
    for b in s2:
        for c in s3:
             # do stuff. a, b, c is the combination
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see working solution below using xlwings.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r'C:\somepath')
sht = wb.sheets('Fields')
s1 = sht.range('A1:A10')
s2 = sht.range('B1:B12')

for a in s1:
    for b in s2:
        print (a.value + "," + b.value)
```