# Excel, Python, Sorting Cells by header

Tags: python, vba, excel, sorting

I'm looking to develop a code that incorporates two worksheets, and sorting the values into a yes/no header for each value into another sheet.

There are 300 headers, from a data sheet that provides random test values each time. Example AA, or BF, CG-G etc.

I would like to take these values, and place them into another header within the same row.

Example:

```
Constant | Value Headers
AWI WELL | AA | BB | CC | DD etc 
AGF WELL | CC | BB | LL | FF etc
```

To something like this

```
Constant | AA | BB | CC | DD | FF
AWI WELL | YES| YES| YES| YES| NO
AGF WELL | NO | YES| YES| NO | YES
```

Is this possible? Psuedo looking at

```
 If cell value == header(header_name):
      header(header_value) == YES
 else:
      header(header_value) == no
```

Anyone that could be able to point me in the direction on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in python :
you should first read your file you can maybe use panda :

```
import pandas as pd
TheFile = pd.read_excel(path + filename)
```

And then read it with a `for` loop cell by cell do the operation you need to do.

and then write in a new file, if you need excel file : 
[Python - Write to Excel Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet)
or : http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Send some code and we will be able to help you more specifically !