# How to force dictionary elements to be written in order?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I am trying to write from Python into an Excel workbook using XlsxWriter.
I have a dictionary called `Pg` whose keys are tuples.

```
for key,value in Pg.iteritems():
     for t in range(1,4):
      if key==(0,t):
       worksheet.write(row,col,value.x)
       row += 1
```

I want to write values of key (0,t) in a column, but the values don't appear in normal order. For example, if my dictionary looks like this:

```
Pg={(0,1):1,(0,2):2,(0,3):3}
```

I get in Excel:

```
1
3
2
```

Why is this happening when I have strictly determined in the second `for` loop how I want my values to be written?

Comment: Answers here.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Write to Excel Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the linked question. I've revised the subject line to more accurately reflect the thrust of this question. (It is very likely a duplicate of, or at least related to, *other* questions about Python dictionaries and how to order them. Simply writing to Excel is not the main issue here.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you realize that when you iterate over a dictionary, you are not guaranteed any specific ordering. The problem you are having is that the way you are trying to force an ordering is flawed.

```
for key,value in Pg.iteritems():
    for t in range(1,4):
        if key==(0,t):
            # ...
```

What this does is iterate over each `key, value` pair first. Then inside this you output if the key matches a certain condition. If you switched the ordering of the `for` loops, you would get what you wanted, but this method is not efficient at all.

More simply, you can iterate over the sorted dictionary like this:

```
for key, value in sorted(Pg.iteritems()):
    worksheet.write(row, col, value.x)
    row += 1
```