# Send output with creating dynamic sheets into excel

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple router/switches. I want to read router Ip address from csv file and write the outputs into an excel. In excel I want to create sheets per device.

I can connect and get the outputs with the code below but couldnt create excel and multiple dynamic sheets in it. I tried xlsxwriter and xlwt, what is your suggestion?

```
router = {}
output_dict = {}

with open('Devices.csv', mode='r') as devicesFile:
    devicesDict = csv.DictReader(devicesFile, dialect = 'excel')
    for row in devicesDict:
        devicetype = row['device_type']
        hostname = row['hostname']
        ipaddress = row['ip']
        username = row['username']
        password = row['password']
        router = {'host':hostname,'device_type':devicetype,'ip':ipaddress,'username':username,'password':password, }
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**router)
        output = net_connect.send_command('display clock')
        print('\n\n>>> Hostname {0} <<<'.format(row['hostname']))
        print(output)
        print('>>>>>>>>> End <<<<<<<<<')


def net_connect(row, output_q):
       ipaddress = row['ip']
       output_dict[ipaddress] = output
       output_q.put(output_dict)
```

Comment: hi @ferdi, why don't you use `xlwt`?

Comment: I tried but couldnt create the sheets with hostnames. Do you have similar code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437772/2572645 @ferdi

Comment: thanks for the links. I can write the outputs per excel sheet and excel sheets are device hostnames. My other problem is all output is being written into one cell, for ex A1 with the "sh.write(0, 0, output)" command.                  
How can I write the outputs in excel like I did copy paste into excel sheet? using multiple rows for output.

Comment: I could do this with "enumerate(output.splitlines())".. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working code is as below. This splits the output lines in excel.

```
for y, line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    rowx = y + 3       
    for x, value in enumerate(line.splitlines()):
        colx = x + 2
        if value.isdigit():
            value = int(value)
        sh.write(rowx, colx, value)
```