# How can I put two values in one index of list to store it in excel file on row + cellvalue?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, python-2.7, wxpython

I want to add two values in one index of list like

```
['18' 'PASS','19' 'FAIL','20' 'PASS','21' '' FAIL]
```

and then put this value in excel sheet like  18th row put value 'PASS'.

Comment: if(i==1) put value pass in row 18

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check out [How to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You list will become like `['18PASS', '19FAIL'...]` its better to store a tuple as element of list like `[(18,'PASS')...]`

Comment: You should use 'python' and the pythong that you are using as tags (so `python` + `python-3.x` it you use `python 3`. The python tag will adress all pythonians on SO, the -3.x you need due to differences between 2 and 3. Are you really using wxpython ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have multiple values in "one index of a list" you can simply use a list of tuples:

```
myTupleList= [(1,"one"),(2,"two"),(3,"three")]
```

If you want to store something as excel table (which is in and of itself 2 dimensional), you would need at least 3 things:

```
myData = [(row_1,column_1,data_1), ..., (row_n,col_n,data_n)]
```

to enable arbitary placement inside a excel workboot sheet.

Lets create some demo data:

```
header = [ (0,idx,n) for idx,n in enumerate(["number","number^2","number^3"])] 

data = [ (n, 0, n) for n in range(0,30,3)]
data += [ (n, 1, n ** 2) for n in range(0,30,3)]
data += [ (n, 2, n ** 3) for n in range(0,30,3)]

# header: [(0, 0, 'number'), (0, 1, 'number^2'), (0, 2, 'number^3')]

# data: [(0, 0, 0),    (3, 0, 3),   (6, 0, 6),   (9, 0, 9),   (12, 0, 12), (15, 0, 15), 
#        (18, 0, 18),  (21, 0, 21), (24, 0, 24), (27, 0, 27), (0, 1, 0),   (3, 1, 9), 
#        (6, 1, 36),   (9, 1, 81),  (12, 1, 144),(15, 1, 225),(18, 1, 324),(21, 1, 441), 
#        (24, 1, 576), (27, 1, 729), (0, 2, 0),  (3, 2, 27),   (6, 2, 216), (9, 2, 729), 
#        (12, 2, 1728),(15, 2, 3375),(18, 2, 5832),(21, 2, 9261),(24, 2, 13824), 
#        (27, 2, 19683)]
```

And then write the data into workbooks:

```
writeXlsWorkbook("text.xls","computed Numbers", header, data)
writeXlsxWorkbook("text.xlsx","computed Numbers", header, data)
```

Writing old excel files (*.xls):

```
import xlwt    
def writeXlsWorkbook(filename:str, sheet:str, header:list, tupleData:list):
    """Write xls to filename, place data on sheet with sheet as name.

    'header' and 'tupleData' are 3 dimensional zero based tuples of (row,column, data). 
    If 'header' is given, 'tupleData' will be placed in the row below the header-row."""
    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sh = book.add_sheet(sheet)

    addToRowsNr = 0
    if header:
        for row, col, data in header:
            sh.write(row , col , data)
        addToRowsNr = 1

    for row, col, data in tupleData:
        sh.write(row + addToRowsNr, col , data)

    book.save(filename)
```

Writing new excel files (*.xlsx):

```
import openpyxl 
def writeXlsxWorkbook(filename:str, sheet:str, header:list, tupleData:list):
    """Write xlsx to filename, place data on sheet with sheet as name.

    'header' and 'tupleData' are 3 dimensional zero based tuples of (row,column, data). 
    If 'header' is given, 'tupleData' will be placed in the row below the header-row."""
    book = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sh = book.active # get the one default sheet
    sh.title = sheet # rename it

    # sh.cell( ..) is 1-based, data is 0 based so we add one to row and col
    addToRowsNr = 0
    if header:
        for row, col, data in header:
            sh.cell(row=row+1, column=col+1, value=data) # ws['B4'] = "42" would work
        addToRowsNr = row+2

    for row, col, data in tupleData:
        sh.cell(row = row + addToRowsNr, column = col + 1, value = data)

    book.save(filename)
```

---

To write your data you would supply:

```
# zero based data, hence -1 on the row
writeXlsWorkbook("somename.xls","someSheetName",None, [(18-1,0, 'PASS'),
                          (19-1,0,'FAIL'),(20-1,0,'PASS'),(21-1,0,'FAIL')] )

writeXlsxWorkbook("somename.xlsx","someSheetName",None, [(18-1,0, 'PASS'),
                           (19-1,0,'FAIL'),(20-1,0,'PASS'),(21-1,0,'FAIL')] )
```

Links:

- [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook)
- [xlwt](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt)

Disclaimer: I took a peek at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437772/7505395) for the old style excel writing 
 and heavily adapted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of tuples

For example

```
lst = [(18, 'Pass'), (19, 'Fail')]
```

You can access the values as

```
lst[1] --> (19, 'Fail')
lst[1][0] --> 19
lst[1][1] --> 'Fail'
```

**Please Note:**

- Tuples are immutable, so cannot add new elements
- Merging of tuples with the + operator you can add an element and it will create a new tuple

You can read more about this over [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: i got your point but if i have a empty tuples how can i add in that tuples please if you give one small exam like above

Comment: @jaymingaudana, take a look at this: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/tuple/python-tuple-exercise-5.php

Comment: where is the excel part?

Comment: actually 18,19,20 are my row number so i want to put my result pass or fail in that row so...

Comment: how to append  in this list?

Answer (score 0):

Possible options are

**1. One string with seperator**

`>>> list = ['18 PASS', '19 FAIL', '20 PASS']`

```
>>> list[0].split()
['18', 'PASS']

>>> list[0].split()[0]
'18'

>>> list[0].split()[1]
'PASS'

>>> list = ['18|PASS', '19|FAIL', '20|PASS']

>>> list[0].split('|')
['18', 'PASS']

>>> list[0].split('|')[0]
'18'

>>> list[0].split('|')[1]
'PASS'
```

Here you store the information as 1 string with a separator, usually space. And whenever needed you parse it.

**Caution**: Though the separator can e any character or string,  you should be extra careful that you separator should not appear in the information string.

For example,
lets go out of your example and take age and name

```
>>> list = ['48 Torvalds', '62 Rossum', '62 Grady Booch']

>>> list[0].split()[1]
'Torvalds'

>>> list[1].split()[1]
'Rossum'

>>> list[2].split()[1]
'Grady'
```

Ouch!! you missed the last name Booch.

**2. List of lists or list of tuples**

As explained in previous answer by [https://stackoverflow.com/users/3287355/user3287355](http://user3287355)

Remember **tuples are immutable**, once created you cannot alter the contents.

**3. Recommended to use Python Dictionary**

For key-value pairs Python has a built-in structure called Dictionary which analogous to Map, JSON etc.

```
>>> dict = {'18':'PASS', '19':'FAIL', '20':'PASS'}

>>> dict.get('18')
'PASS'

>>> dict.get('19')
'FAIL'

>>> dict.get('20')
'PASS'
```

**Caution**: Beware of duplicate keys. Also you can't expect the dictionary to preserve the order of elements as you entered. However its completely based on key-value, we don't get values by index.

Comment: where is the excel part?