# Python - error on 'get_sheet_by_name'

Tags: python, openpyxl

This is my code so far:

```
import os
import openpyxl
os.chdir('C:\\Python34\\MyPy')
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

But I get these errors:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     /File "**main**", line 1
>   DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_names (Use wb.sheetnames).
>   ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']

Comment: looks like a warning and not an error

Comment: Hi all, I get an error due to using  'get_sheet_by_name' when I write the above code. I tried using the 'sheetnames' function  instead as mentioned in the error, but can't get it to work. Anyone?? thanks..

Comment: True, it's a warning, but nothing seems to work after that. Using 'wb.sheetnames()' instead of get_sheet_names gives another error

Comment: can you paste the new code and traceback?

Comment: Ah, think I figured it out.... putting 'wb.sheetnames' on the next line works. I entered 'wb.sheetnames()' before - doesn't like the (). Thx Usernamenotfound

Comment: "I get a warning" isn't really a problem. "I get an error after changing my code because of a warning" _is_ a problem, but we need to see your changed code, and the error you get, and what you expected to happen; seeing your old code and the warning you got doesn't help.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting question. However, If the warning is not the problem -- please ask a specif question as to what the real problem is. What is it not doing that it should? "It doesn't work" does not give the reader enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 16):

Warnings aren't errors - they won't hinder your program from running. In case of `deprecated warnings`: you use a feature that will be removed in future versions so the devs lable it deprecated.

It may work now, but next version it may no longer as this feature was removed - *then* you will get an error.

You can fix it like this:

> ```
> wb.sheetnames # all names
>
> sheet = wb["UseThisSheet"]  # select a certain sheet by name
>
> for sheet2 in wb:           # or go over all sheets 
>     print(sheet2.title)
>
> sh = wb.active             # normally sheet at index 0 if you create an empy one
> ```
>
> Source: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Here is a short example on how to create a workbook (my answer to some other xlsx question): https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782382/7505395

Answer (score 1):

Since I bounce around in a few different worksheets in my python, I needed the whole list to work from.  I added the following

```
wbInputFile = load_workbook(inFile)
sheetList = wbInputFile.sheetnames
worksheet = wbInputFile[ sheetList[0] ]

#  now I am able to run through the rows and get the info
for row in range(2,worksheet.max_row ):
    # get the values for each cell needed
```

Answer (score 0):

It gives a warning , but the below code works fine (using Python3 ).I tried with wb.sheetnames instead of wb.get_sheet_names()

```
import openpyxl
path="C:\\Users\user1\PycharmProjects\Projectstatus\My Python.xlsx"
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 #Load in the workbook
 wb = load_workbook('YourFileName.xlsx')
 wb.sheetnames # all names
```