# How to write a data into an exist sheet of excel file by Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwt

I'm looking for a way to write some data into an excel file. Then I found `xlwt` seems can reach my requirement, but I only find the way to add a new sheet.
for example:

```
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test222')
```

If I hope to enter a value into an exist sheet "test 111", does someone know how to do that?

My sample code:

```
import xlwt

def write_report():
    f_value = "500"
    workbook = xlwt.Workbook('D:\\Test.xls')
    sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test222')
    sheet.write(5, 3, f_value)

    workbook.save('D:\\Test.xls')
```

Thanks a lot.

[Update on 7/31/2018]
After I used the method of import openpyxl, I met a weird issue.
Some borders were disappeared after I write data into the file.
Original:
[image]

After I wrote data into the file:
[image]

The border of some fields which have been merged were cleared. (item A, item B, Category 01 and Category 02)
Is it the known issue on openpyxl?

Comment: I think you can take a look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet

Comment: @LêTưThành - actually it is quite a nice link, but only one of the answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979532/5448626 answers to the question of the OP. However, that answer is from 2015 and the function `get_sheet_by_name` is depreciated by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is minmal example:

```
import openpyxl

wbkName = 'New.xlsx'
wbk = openpyxl.load_workbook(wbkName)
wks = wbk['test1']
someValue = 1337
wks.cell(row=10, column=1).value = someValue
wbk.save(wbkName)
wbk.close
```

The saving with the explicit name of the workbook seems to be quite important  - `wbk.save(wbkName)`, because only `wbk.save` does not do the job completely, but does not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xltpl](https://pypi.org/project/xltpl/) for this - A python module to generate xls/x files from a xls/x template.

Use your excel file as the template.
Put variables in the cells, such as : `{{f_value}}, {%xv someValue%}`

```
from xltpl.writer import BookWriter
writer = BookWriter('template.xls')
payload = {"f_value": "500", "someValue": 1337}
payloads = [payload]
writer.render_book(payloads)
writer.save('result.xls')
```