# Creating Excel File From Bash Script output with python

Tags: python, bash

I have an output file which created from a `bash` script.

that output file is:

```
   xyz|xxx.local|Protocol 2|Root Acces Denied
   xyz|xxx1.local|Protocol 2|Root Acces Denied
```

I am trying to create Excel file from this which is going to be

```
 Column1  Column2     Column3       Column4
  xyz    xxx.local   Protocol 2  Root Acces Denied
  xyz    xxx.local   Protocol 2  Root Acces Denied
```

How can I do this with Python?

Comment: using [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that pretty very elegantly with pandas Dataframes. Check [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

If you are new to Python and you haven't worked with pandas so far, I recommend you to look up Python/xls questions here in stackoverflow (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet)) and try those, before jumping on pandas.

Anyway, if you need a quick solution copy & paste this

```
import pandas as pd

# Load your bash output file in pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('bash_outfile.out', sep='|', names=['Column1', 'Column2',
                                                     'Column3', 'Column4'])

# Open pandas ExcelWriter and write to *.xls file
with pd.ExcelWriter('my_xls.xls') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

which will do what you want.