# transforming text to excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I'm all new in Python but I have one interesting task. 
We have very big structural text. 
EXAMPLE:

'''

```
Writers 1.
Writer Dostoevsky, career: 1844-1849 (early career), 1849-1854 (exile to Siberia), 1854-1866 (prison, marriage).
Writer Pushkin, career: 1820-1822 (first publishing), 1836-1837 (duels and death).
Writers 2.
Writer Shakespeare, career: 1585-1588 (career beginning).
Writer Hemingway, career: 1913-1917 (high school), 1916-1917 (first publishing), 1818-1819 (World War I).
Writer Twain, career: 1883-1909 (Love of science and technology).
```

'''

We need to transform it excel spreadsheet to get clear view of information:

[image: The Excel spreadsheet]

How can i solve it? I tried to use regular expressions, but I guess it's not enough to get the spreadsheet, like in the picture.

Comment: Are you looking write to an Excel sheet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/writing-to-an-excel-spreadsheet

Comment: Do you need to use Python?  If this text is in Excel, it can readily be transformed using `Power Query` (available in Excel 2010+)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the xlwt library. You can find that [here](https://pypi.org/project/xlwt/)

```
# Writing to an excel  
# sheet using Python 
import xlwt 
from xlwt import Workbook 

# Workbook is created 
wb = Workbook() 

# add_sheet is used to create sheet. 
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1') 

sheet1.write(1, 0, 'ISBT DEHRADUN') 
sheet1.write(2, 0, 'SHASTRADHARA') 
sheet1.write(3, 0, 'CLEMEN TOWN') 
sheet1.write(4, 0, 'RAJPUR ROAD') 
sheet1.write(5, 0, 'CLOCK TOWER') 
sheet1.write(0, 1, 'ISBT DEHRADUN') 
sheet1.write(0, 2, 'SHASTRADHARA') 
sheet1.write(0, 3, 'CLEMEN TOWN') 
sheet1.write(0, 4, 'RAJPUR ROAD') 
sheet1.write(0, 5, 'CLOCK TOWER') 

wb.save('xlwt example.xls')
```

[sauce](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-excel-sheet-using-python/)