# Writing output to excel file in python

Tags: python, selenium, output, xlwt

I am new in Python. I use xlwt so I am having a problem with writing outputs to excel file.

I have an output data like:

```
[['Alex'], [23, 40], ['Food', 'Clothes']]
[['Andy'], [10, 23], ['Telephone', 'Games']]
```

I just want data is written like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm9aJ.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to an Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/writing-to-an-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: Check this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that your input is some collections of lists. You can create an empty Dataframe and add each list as new rows separately. See below:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Amount', 'Spendings'])

for x in your_lists:
    for i in range(len(x[1])):
        df.loc[len(df)]=[x[0][0], x[1][i], x[2][i]]

df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

>>> print(df)

     Amount  Spendings
Name
Alex     23       Food
Alex     40    Clothes
Andy     10  Telephone
Andy     23      Games
```