# Export XLSX from custom python plugin for qgis

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

With this code included in custom plugin for QGIS I write  on a csv file all the layer features and for each feature I do some actions.

```
        line1 = ';'.join(name for name in fieldnames)+';'+'note'+';'+'grandezze_misurate'+';'+'PIC_1'+';'+'PIC_2'+';'+'PIC_QR'+';'+'PIC_GE'+';'+'PIC_PLAN'+'\n'
        output_file.write(line1)
        

        # request = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest()
        # set order by field
         #clause = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause(id, ascending=True)
         #orderby = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([clause])
         #request.setOrderBy(orderby)

        # add some layer
       
        #features = selectedLayer.getFeatures(request)
     
        # wirte feature attributes
        #request = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest()
        #clause = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderByClause('id_mis', ascending=True)
        #orderby = qgis.core.QgsFeatureRequest.OrderBy([clause])
        #request.setOrderBy(orderby)
        for feat in selectedLayer.getFeatures():
          
            id = feat['id']
            x = str(feat['long'])
            y = str(feat['lat'])
            #print(id+" "+x+" "+ y)
            Path(QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")+'/'+selectedLayer.name()+'/IMMAGINI/').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            img = qrcode.make('https://www.google.com/maps?q='+y+','+x,box_size=2.9)
            img.save(QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")+'/'+selectedLayer.name()+'/IMMAGINI/'+id+'_QR.png')
            download_url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+y+','+x+'&zoom=17&size=640x301&maptype=hyb&sensor=false&scale=1&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7C'+y+','+x+'&key=AIzaSyCennHOjhBlpHeFPI-VbD24O8GEkXCXDbE'
            #print('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+y+','+x+'&zoom=17&size=640x301&maptype=sat&sensor=false&scale=1&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7C'+y+','+x+'&key=AIzaSyCennHOjhBlpHeFPI-VbD24O8GEkXCXDbE')
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url,QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")+'/'+selectedLayer.name()+'/IMMAGINI/'+id+'_GE.png')
            PATH =str(QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")+'/'+selectedLayer.name()+'/IMMAGINI/')
            a=PATH.replace("/","\\\\")
            line = ';'.join(str(feat[name]) for name in fieldnames) +';'+';'+';'+a+id+'_1.jpg'+';'+a+id+'_2.jpg'+';'+a+id+'_QR.png'+';'+a+id+'_GE.png'+';'+a+id+'_PLAN.jpg'+'\n'
            output_file.write(line)
```

**I need to write on a xlsx instead of a csv**

**any suggestion?**

thanks

Comment: I suggest to use a library that can write xlsx files and replace the code that writes a csv file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to an Excel spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/writing-to-an-excel-spreadsheet)