# How to write date in excel file in python

Tags: python, excel

Hi i want to write in excel file output from my program in Python.
This program ping every ip adress from txt file.

This is my code:

```
import os

with open("ip.txt", "r+") as ips_file:
    ips = [ip.strip() for ip in ips_file.readlines()]

with open("IPsCheck.txt", "w") as available_ips_file:
    for ip in ips:
        response = os.system('ping {} -n 2 -w 2'.format(ip))
        if response == 0:
            available_ips_file.write(ip + "\n")
        else:
            print('server {} not available'.format(ip))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/how-to-write-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-python

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `pandas`. This package has a `to_excel` method for data. Take a look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).