# output the data on request

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis

Good afternoon here. Please help with the start (algorithm) of the program.
I have an excel file that has columns with the *names* of students, their *last names*, their *phone numbers*, what *country* they are from and their *marks*.

How can I write a python program with which I can input something of the data (*phone number, name or surname*) and I have to output all the data about the student, all that is known about him. And preferably in a separate file (excel, csv). Thanks for the help.

excel file:

| Name | Last Name | Phone number | Country | Mark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | Jackson | 5534987 | USA | A |
| Ani | Ward | 4567456 | UK | A |
| Alex | Sid | 7745879 | France | C |

If anything, I don't know how to use json and sql. But if it will be easier, than ok.

I entering: 7745879
Output:
| Alex   | Sid          |  7745879 | France          | C          |

My code only reads the file. I don't know what to do next.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
file = 'Students.xlsx'

x1=pd.ExcelFile(file)

df1=x1.parse('Math')

for line in df1:
  print(df1.loc[:, 'Phone number'])
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input as text.

Comment: Or take a look at https://realpython.com/python-csv/ .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to an Excel spreadsheet using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/how-to-write-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-python)

Comment: and i want to input phone number (as example:  7745879 ) and to output all data about student, who have this number. Output (Alex Sid France 7745879 C)

Comment: @rajah9 thanks, but I need to understand the technique of how you can find all the data on a student by request.. For example, I made an input a phone number and I should get all the data about the owner of this number.

Comment: You need to understand a Python if statement. I suggest you look at existing programs on geeksforgeeks or realpython.

Comment: This is a lot of questions in one. You have the requirements/specs for an entire program and your question amounts to "How do I develop this program from these specs". It's wildly broad for stackoverflow. Instead concentrate on each individual problem. An appropriate question for this site would be: "If I have a string to search for in an excel worksheet (column D) how do I perform that search? Heres my attempt so far <your non-working code>, but I'm stuck here <specific spot you are unable to overcome>"

Comment: @JNevill ok, I published that code, but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That's great! It really helps to understand that you are using pandas dataframes to pull in the excel data. Can you share what that dataframe looks like (just like top 5 records in the DF). Likely your `.loc()` or similar filtering is the right path forward.

Comment: @JNevill thanks! 0    5534987
1    4567456
2    7745879
3    5634876
4    7755123
5    3499759
6    9934555
Name: Phone number, dtype: int64                                                                                        that what I have in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check across all the entries in each row of your `DataFrame` to see if any value matches with your input -

```py
inp = input("Enter something:\t")
# Enter something:        7745879
out_df = pd.DataFrame([rec for rec in df.values if any([inp == str(val) for val in rec])], columns=df.columns)
```

The list comprehension is doing the same thing as the following for loops - which are easier to understand -

```py
for rec in df.values:
    for val in rec:
        if inp == str(val):
            out_df = pd.DataFrame([rec for rec in df.values if any([inp == str(val) for val in rec])], columns=df.columns)
```

**Output**

```
   Name Last Name  Phone number Country Mark
0  Alex       Sid       7745879  France    C
```

You can then write this `out_df` to an excel with something like `out_df.to_excel(f'output_for_{inp}.xlsx')`