Python list to excel
new to coding. I have a question concerning lists within Python and putting said list into an excel file. My list is similar to as follows.
List1 =
[[[a,1], [b,2], [c,3], [d,4], [e,5]],
[[aa,11], [bb,22], [cc,33], [dd,44],[ee,55]],
[[aaa,111], [bbb,222], [ccc,333], [ddd,444],[eee,555]],
[[aaaa,1111], [bbbb,2222], [cccc,3333], [dddd,4444],[eeee,5555]],

Lets say my list is a lot bigger than that but same amount of elements in each list as seen above. Now my goal is for it to save to excel something like this Excel sheet
So far in my code, I have imported pandas and its reading from an excel file and I want it to copy to an excel file.
Thank you

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/how-to-write-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-python
